# Setting up mitmproxy and wireguard using mitmproxy's python API

Tags: python, mitmproxy, wireguard

I'm trying to configure a mitmproxy instance to use wireguard to route through a remote server, where the data is processed with an Addon(). Essentially I would like to run the following command with custom keys through python:

```
mitmdump -s addon.py --mode wireguard
```

But to use my own keys/etc, I'd prefer to pass it through the python API (theoretically I could add it to /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf but I've had mixed results). I've had a hard time understanding how to use it though, as I've only had bits and pieces of code to go by. This is what I have so far:

```
wg_server = await mitmproxy_wireguard.start_server(
    "0.0.0.0",
    51820,
    server_privkey,
    [client_pubkey],
    handle_connection,
    receive_datagram,
)

options = Options()
master = DumpMaster(options)
# master.addons.add(Addon()) # when I uncomment this it no longer connects
master.server = wg_server
```

And the following callbacks:

```
async def handle_connection(rw: mitmproxy_wireguard.TcpStream):
    while True:
        data = await rw.read(4096)

        # check if the connection was closed
        if len(data) == 0:
            break

        rw.write(data)
        await rw.drain()

    rw.close()

def receive_datagram(_data, _src_addr, _dst_addr):
    master.server.send_datagram(data.upper(), dst_addr, src_addr)
```

This is all in an asyncio loop I left out for clarity.

No matter what I do I can't get it to connect properly. With and without the addon it will increment up in RX and TX byte counts on the client (so they are communicating), and with tcpdump I can see that some data is getting to the server, however it won't render a webpage on a browser on the client's machine. I can't even ping google from the client.

Client conf file wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = {clientPrivKey}
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 77.88.8.7

[PEER]
PublicKey = {serverPubKey}
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = {serverIPAddr}:{portNumber}
```

I think the issue may have something to do with DNS, however I'm not completely sure. At the very least the DNS isn't getting through as well as everything else, as I only see it in tcpdump and not the destinations real address. If anyone has any insight into using the [mitmproxy_wireguard](https://github.com/decathorpe/mitmproxy_wireguard) package I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks you for your time/help, and let me know if you have any questions about my setup

Answer (score 0):

So I am not aware of any way to do this from python, and have given up. What I did end up discovering is you can add a [port and configuration path](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#wireguard-transparent-proxy) to wireguard through the terminal:

```
mitmdump -s addon.py --mode wireguard:/path/to/wireguard.conf@51820
```

Where wireguard.conf looks like:

```
{
    "server_key": "SERVER PRIVATE KEY",
    "client_key": "CLIENT PRIVATE KEY"
}
```

Unfortunately this still takes a server public key and a client public key, which is bad if you don't want to share your client private key with a server. What I ended up doing is forking mitmproxy and modifying the key reader such that it only needs the client public key.

My change [can be viewed here](https://github.com/thansen0/mitmproxy-pubkey/commit/83e9e7745a57161bf4429e2682da8efca57dd2a6), and you can see all I do is instead of converting the private key to a public key, I just leave it as a public key. however I would recommend creating your own fork as my fork may change at any given moment. The file which needs to be changed is `mitmproxy/proxy/mode_servers.py`

From here you can install it into any pip3 environment by cloning it, making your edits, and then running `pip3 install .`

To run in python, I then run the command using subprocess.run:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["mitmdump", "-s", "addon.py", "--mode", f"wireguard:{conf_file_path}@{wg_port}"])
```

Not very elegant but it's working.